# Mixing numpy floats and regular python float giving error

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a python function to predict the motion of a projectile under the influence of gravity. I seem to get an error. Most articles I have read can't seem to help resolve the error.
PS: I am a Python newbie so be kind in your criticism if any.

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def projectile_motion(initial_velocity, angle, time_step, total_time):
    m = 1.0
    g = 9.8
    k = 0.42
    x=[0]
    y=[0]
    angle_rad = angle/180 * np.pi
    new_velocity = 0
    
    #Calculate initial vx and vy
    vx = [initial_velocity * np.cos(angle_rad)]
    vy = [initial_velocity * np.sin(angle_rad)]      
    
    #Initial Drag Force due to air friction
    drag_force = k * initial_velocity**2
    
    #Calculate acceleration components
    ax =[-(drag_force * np.cos(angle_rad))  / m]
    ay = [-g - (drag_force * np.sin(angle_rad)) / m]    
    
    
    list_size = int(total_time/time_step)      
   
    for i in range(list_size):
       vx.append(vx[i] + time_step * ax[i])
       vy.append(vy[i] + time_step * ay[i])
       x.append(x[i] + time_step * vx[i])
       y.append(y[i] + time_step * vy[i])
      
       #Calculate magnitude of new velocity 
       new_velocity = np.sqrt(vx[i+1]**2 + vy[i+1]**2)
       
       #Calculate magnitude of new drag_force
       drag_force = k * new_velocity**2
       
       ax.append([-(drag_force * np.cos(angle_rad))  / m])
       ay.append([-g - (drag_force * np.sin(angle_rad)) / m])        
       print(x)
       print(y)
    
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show
    return

projectile_motion(10, 45.0, 0.01, 2)
```

Comment: `sequence` means a list, string or something else for which `*` means 'replicate'.

Answer (score 2):

In these lines you append a list to a list:

```
ax.append([-(drag_force * np.cos(angle_rad))  / m])
ay.append([-g - (drag_force * np.sin(angle_rad)) / m])
```

This will result in this structure ax = [ax0, [ax1]]. Now your code will fail in the second iteration since you're trying the multiply the `timestep` with `[ax1]` which is a list and hence throws a error since it's not possible.

Changing the lines of appending to this:

```
ax.append(-(drag_force * np.cos(angle_rad))  / m)
ay.append(-g - (drag_force * np.sin(angle_rad)) / m)
```

Now instead of a list containing the value, you only append the value. After two iterations you'll have ax = [ax0, ax1] instead of ax = [ax0, [ax1]]. In this case your code can be executed.

Comment: In addition to this - you'll need to change `plt.show` to `plt.show()`.